# Apply Stokes theorem on a triangle

Tags: multivariable-calculus

**Q:** Use Stokes theorem to calculate $\int_\gamma u\cdot\,\mathrm dr$ where $\gamma$ is the rand to the triangle in $xy$-plane with the vertices being $(0,0,0), (1,0,0)$ and $(0,1,0)$ clockwise. And$$u=(x \cos x \sin x+y, y-z, x+z^3).$$

**S:**  The theorem says that:
$$\int_{d Y} u \cdot\,\mathrm dr = \iint(\operatorname{rot} u) \cdot N\,\mathrm dS$$
And I have draw my triangle like this:

[image]

and goes like $A \to B \to C$. Therefore $N=(0,0,1)$.

But my question here is what/how should I do with the $\mathrm dS$?

Answer (score 1):

The $dS$ is just an element of area. In practice, you should calculate the curl (or rot, whatever you want to call it) of the vector field $u$, and dot it with the normal to the triangle. That will just give you the $z$-component of the curl (as you already pointed out, $N = (0,0,1)$). The resulting scalar function can be integrated over the triangular region. Let me know if you need further advice.

Comment: Ooh! So curl(u) = (1,-1,1) and (1,-1,1) \cdot (0,0,1) = 1 ... but I don't know what do to with  the gamma.. could you just multiply the scalar, 1.. with the area of a triangle? Or what shall my limits be?  since I have two integrals.

Comment: So indeed, integrating 1 over the triangle just gives you the area of the triangle. Normally, you would have to do the double integral by choosing a convenient order. For example, you could do: $\int_{0}^1 \int_{0}^{1-x} 1* dy * dx$. In this case, though, you don't need to go through these steps, because you're just integrating a constant function.

Comment: so just $\int_0^1 \int_0^{1-x} 1 dxdy = 1/2$  that is just the 'proof' that I can just do it the same as taking the area of a triangle (just because it is a constant)..  But one thing though... Stokes theorem is saying that is has to be a closed curve.. what about the vector from $y \in [0,1]$ ie. my C in my picture

Comment: You could view $\iint_A 1 * dy * dx$ as the "definition" of area for a certain shape $A$. It doesn't really matter if you solve the integral, or compute it using an elementary geometric argument. 

I don't understand what you mean by your last point.

Comment: @Wizard.. Just that Stokes theorem says that "Stoke's Theorem. is the curl of the vector field F. The symbol ∮ indicates that the line integral is taken over a _closed curve_. " A closed curve. but mine isn't closed? Thinking of since we just integrate over 0,1 and 0, 1-x ?

Comment: The bounds 0,1 and 0,$1-x$ are for the area which is bounded by your closed curve (the boundary of the triangle). There is no problem there.

Comment: @Wizard, but what happens if we go anti-clockwise? just a curious question :) then N=(0,0,-1) and we'll ge this negative instead?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You would just get a minus sign.

Comment: @Wizact I have a smilar issue. I want to calculate vorticity over a latitude circle on the geographic poles. Because I am using a spherical model the vorticity has a 1/cos theta scale factor and this blows up at the poles. So I want to calculate use Stokes theorem and calculate the vorticity as a circulation. Any suggestions ?